Angular Material List not rendering list properly when the list item is a component
Objective
I am attempting to encapsulate the formatting logic (not routing logic) into a component.
I am using the Angular Material's MatList component.
<mat-nav-list>
  <!-- The below <a> has some common routing and styling logics  -->
  <a
    mat-list-item
    [class.active]="isActive"
    routerLinkActive="active2"
    [activated]="isActive"
    [routerLink]="link"
  >
    <!-- Control formatting -->
    @if(singleLine) {
    <app-list-single-line-format [item]="item" />
    } @else {
    <app-list-multi-line-format [item]="item" />
    }
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>

It is almost working. But the styling is broken when used as a component.
Minimal reproduction
<mat-nav-list role="list">
  <!-- working -->
  <a mat-list-item role="listitem">
    <mat-icon matListItemIcon>folder</mat-icon>
    <div matListItemTitle>hello</div>
    <div matListItemLine>world</div>
  </a>

  <!-- Broken styles -->
  <a mat-list-item role="listitem">
    <app-list-item />
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>


Styling of the second item is broken. I don't want to fix this by hacky css. Is there a proper way? Stackblitz
Excerpt:
@Component({
  selector: "app-list-item",
  template: `
    <mat-icon matListItemIcon>folder</mat-icon>
    <div matListItemTitle>hello</div>
    <div matListItemLine>world</div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatListModule, MatIconModule, RouterLink],
})
export class ListItem {}

@Component({
  selector: "list-overview-example",
  template: `
    <mat-nav-list role="list">
      <!-- working -->
      <a mat-list-item role="listitem">
        <mat-icon matListItemIcon>folder</mat-icon>
        <div matListItemTitle>hello</div>
        <div matListItemLine>world</div>
      </a>

      <!-- Broken styles -->
      <a mat-list-item role="listitem">
        <app-list-item />
      </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatListModule, MatIconModule, RouterLink, ListItem],
})
export class ListOverviewExample {}

Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/3ruxqq?file=src%2Fexample%2Flist-overview-example.html

I think the quickest solution will be you should wrap with <a mat-list-item role="listitem"> in the ListItem component. I think the reason why it is not working is except <mat-icon> element, it will generate <span class="mdc-list-item__content"> and wrap everything inside. Seems your current implementation is working with additional component, instead, your component was wrapped into the <span> element mentioned.

Aside from my concern and curiosity about the purpose of your additional components. If it is just simply for display purposes, I would suggest that you can work by providing the HTML structure directly or with <ng-template> which could save you some time instead of trying to solve the issue resulting from the component.

Unfortunately, the way that you wrap those elements into a separate component is not working when applying it to the mat-list-item element.
mat-list-item has its own structure:
<ng-content select="[matListItemAvatar],[matListItemIcon]"></ng-content>

<span class="mdc-list-item__content">
  <ng-content select="[matListItemTitle]"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="[matListItemLine]"></ng-content>
  <span #unscopedContent class="mat-mdc-list-item-unscoped-content"
        (cdkObserveContent)="_updateItemLines(true)">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </span>
</span>

...


With the additional component, this results in those elements located in the nested HTML element (<app-list-item>), and MatList unable to query for <mat-icon>, matListItemTitle and matListItemLine elements correctly.
Instead, all the elements will be rendered in the <ng-content> part resulting in the styles not working well.
Thus, would suggest you don't need the additional component if that component is just for display and without any additional purpose. Just place the HTML structure within the mat-list-item.
<mat-nav-list>
  <!-- The below <a> has some common routing and styling logics  -->
  <a
    mat-list-item
    [class.active]="isActive"
    routerLinkActive="active2"
    [activated]="isActive"
    [routerLink]="link"
  >
    <!-- Control formatting -->
    @if(singleLine) {
      <mat-icon matListItemIcon>{{ /* item.icon */ }}</mat-icon>
      <div matListItemTitle>{{ /* item.title */ }</div>
      <div matListItemLine>{{ /* item.line */ }</div>
    } @else {
      <!-- HTML Structure from <app-list-multi-line-format> -->
    }
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>

Otherwise, you need to move the <a mat-list-item> to the ListItem component. This requires you to add the @Input binding in the component to receive the data such as isActive, link and etc.
